# Backbone limit/iterate on collection fetch

Tags: backbone.js

Im trying to set a limit on my collection fetch and then iterate over that. I want to fetch lets say 4 items at a time. When i then run fetch the next time i want it to fetch the next 4 items.

My collection looks like this.

```
define([
'Underscore',
'Backbone',
'app',
'StartModel',
], function (_, Backbone, app, StartModel) {

var StartCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
    model: StartModel,  
    url: "url",
    startIndex: 0,
    numItems: 4,
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.data;
    },
    initialize: function() {

    }    
}); 
return StartCollection;
});
```

My fetch function looks like this.(inside a view)

```
render: function(){
var self = this;
if (this.startIndex != -1) {
    this.collection.fetch({
        data: {
            numItems: self.numItems,
            startIndex: self.startIndex
        },
        success: function (collection, response) {
            if (response.length === self.numItems){
                self.startIndex = self.startIndex + self.numItems;
            } else {
          // if the response is less than 4 models you have reached the end of the models
                self.startIndex = -1;
            }
            self.$el.html(self.template);
            _.each(collection.models, function(model,index) {
                self.$el.find(".holder").append("<p>"+model.toJSON+"</p>"())
            });
        }
    });
}
```

},

This is my model

```
define([
'Underscore',
'Backbone',
'app',
], function (_, Backbone, app) {

var StartModel = Backbone.Model.extend({  

    defaults: function() {  
        return {

        };
    },  
    clear: function() {  
        this.destroy();  
    }
}); 
return StartModel;
```

});

Need some help with this. anyone that knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this would be to set up a variable that increments by four each time, sends a request to the server with a flag that indicates which models to return. You can do this by setting a `data` option. Here is a snippet from the [**Backbone docs**](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch):

> jQuery.ajax options can also be passed directly as fetch options, so
>   to fetch a specific page of a paginated collection:
>   Documents.fetch({data: {page: 3}})

[**Here is some documentation for `jQuery.ajax()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Add `startIndex` and `numItems` to your collection:

```
var StartCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
    model: StartModel,  
    url: "url",
    startIndex: 0,
    numItems: 4,
    // ... more code
```

And in your render function send the pertinent information back to the server when you call `fetch`

```
render: function(){
    var self = this;
    if (this.startIndex != -1) {
        this.collection.fetch({
            data: {
                numItems: self.collection.numItems,
                startIndex: self.collection.startIndex
            },
            success: function (collection, response) {
                if (response.length === self.collection.numItems){
                    self.collection.startIndex = self.collection.startIndex +
                       self.collection.numItems;
                } else {
    // if the response is less than 4 models you have reached the end of the models
                    self.collection.startIndex = -1;
                }
                self.$el.html(self.template);
                _.each(collection.models, function(model,index) {
                    self.$el.find(".holder").append(model.toJSON())
                });
            }
        });
    }
},
```

And in your controller in the server, grab `startIndex` and `numItems` from the params and use them to return the correct models to your app.

Comment: Thank you! I run your code now. I run the render() on a click event but all i get in the console is that the startIndex is NaN:

?startIndex=NaN

And nothing gets appended to the DOM. What can the problem be?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the code, in the `data` object, `this.numItems` and `this.startIndex` should have been `self.numItems` and `self.startIndex` because of the change in scope. Try that and see if it works. I have updated the answer.

Comment: No worries. I tried it out but its still NaN though. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your model have the `startIndex` property? Did you assign it in the `StartCollection` class, or when you instantiated the model? If you added the `startIndex` when you instantiated the model, `startIndex` would be added to the model's attribute object, so instead of `self.startIndex` you will need `self.get("startIndex")` and the same with `numItems`.

Comment: I have assigned them in my collection and updated the code in my first post. Maybe i have missed something?

Comment: Hmm, looks like I misunderstood where the `render` was, for some reason I thought it was inside your collection. In your view `this.collection` represents the collection, so inside `fetch` `self.collection` will represent your collection. Try replacing every `self.startIndex` with `self.collection.startIndex` and the same with `numItems`

Comment: Thank you! Now it almost works. The variables get set but on every render() it loads the whole collection again. Not just 4 new Items. So the iterating does not work yet. Any ideas? Appreciete all help!

Comment: If the startIndex and numItems are being added to your query string, that is all you can do on the client side. Well, it isn't all you *can* do, but it is all you *should* do. In the controller of your server you need to use the `startIndex` and `numItems` parameters to retrieve only the models they represent, and then only send those models back as a response. This is out of the control of Backbone.js, it needs to be done server side.